# Can't change button GUIStyle background in EditorWindow

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

*Unity version: 2019.4.1f1*

I'm trying to change background of button in my EditorWindow. Trying to achieve effect pressed button in normal state:
[image]

```
void OnGUI() {
     buttonStyleNormal = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
     buttonStyleToggled = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
     buttonStyleToggled.active.textColor = Color.blue;
     buttonStyleToggled.normal = buttonStyleToggled.active;
     ...
     GUILayout.Button("Developing", buttonStyleToggled);
     GUILayout.Button("Compilation", buttonStyleNormal);
 }
```

Result is here:
[image]

Problem stays even if I set background explicitly:

```
 buttonStyleToggled.normal.background = buttonStyleToggled.active.background;
 buttonStyleToggled.normal.scaledBackgrounds = buttonStyleToggled.active.scaledBackgrounds;
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't see where you set the texture or color for the active state of the button.

```
Color activeButtonColor = new Color(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

buttonStyleToggled.active.background = activeButtonColor;
```

Comment: background is Texture2D, not a Color. buttonStyleToggled.active must already contains texture in background field. And in bottom code block I've set it: buttonStyleToggled.normal.background = buttonStyleToggled.active.background.